# Kotlin inheritance with generics

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, kotlin

I have an abstract class, let's call it A.

```
abstract class A(private val name: String) {

    fun read(key: String): Entity {
        ...
    }

    fun write(entity: Entity) {
        ...
    }

    abstract val mapper: Mapper<Any>

    ...

    interface Mapper<T> {
        fun toEntity(entry: T): Entity

        fun fromEntity(entity: Entity): T
    }

    ...
```

It has an abstract mapper. The point of that is that I can map different objects to Entity and use `read` and `write`.

My child class, let's call it B, is structured like this:

```
class B(private val name: String) : A(name) {
    override val mapper = AnimalMapper

    object AnimalMapper: Mapper<Animal> {
        override fun fromEntity(entity: Entity): Animal {
            TODO("not implemented")
        }

        override fun toEntity(animal: Animal): Entity {
            TODO("not implemented")
        }
    }
}
```

Ideally, I wanted to have an interface in the `Mapper` generic and not `Any`, but I'm simplifying this just for the question.

The issue is that I get this error:

`Type of 'mapper' is not a subtype of the overridden property 'public abstract val mapper: Mapper<Any> defined in ...`

Why is that?

Comment: `A` says that users can map anything. But if the implementation is `B`, they can only map animals. That raises red flags.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Okay, so is there a way to provide what the users can map in the children classes?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Note the two facts about inheritance and generics:

- A `val` property can only be overridden with a subtype of the original property type. That's because all the users of the type expect it to return some instance of the original type. For example, it's okay to override a `CharSequence` property with `String`.

  <sup>A `var` property cannot even use a subtype, only the original type, because the users may want to assign an instance of the original type into the property.</sup>
- Kotlin generics [are invariant by default](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#variance). Given `Mapper<T>`, any two of its instantiations `Mapper<A>` and `Mapper<B>` are not subtypes of each other if `A` and `B` are different.

Given this, you cannot override a property of type `Mapper<Any>` with `Mapper<SomeType>`, because the latter is not a subtype of the former.

You cannot use [declaration-site variance](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#declaration-site-variance) to make all `Mapper<T>` usages covariant (declare the interface as `interface Mapper<out T>`) because of `T` used as the type of a parameter in `fun toEntity(entry: T): Entity`.

You can try to apply [use-site variance](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#use-site-variance-type-projections), declaring the property as

```
abstract val mapper: Mapper<out Any>
```

But this way the users of the class `A` won't be able to call `fun toEntity(entry: T): Entity`, since they will not know what is the actual type that replaces `Any` in the child class and thus what they can safely pass as `entry`. However, if the exact type (e.g. `B`) is known to the user, they will see the type of `mapper` as it is declared in the overridden property.

---

A common pattern that can allow you to use the overridden property in a more flexible way is to parameterize the parent class `class A<T>` and define the property as `val mapper: Mapper<T>`.

This way, the subtypes will have to specify which `T` they use in their declaration: `class B(...) : A<Animal>(...)`, and the users that see `A<Animal>` (even without knowing it's actually `B<Animal>` will safely get its `mapper` as `Mapper<Animal>`.

Comment: I see. Is that true even if in `Mapper<A>` and `Mapper<B>`, `A` is a subtype of `B`? Is the relationship between `A` and `B` irrelevant?

Comment: As a side note, it would be really cleaner for me to be able to call `toEntity` from the parent. What other design could I follow that would allow that? What about passing a `Mapper` as a parameter?

Comment: @pk1914 Yes, if `Mapper<T>` is invariant, `Mapper<A>` and `Mapper<B>` are never subtypes of each other if `A` and `B` are different, including even `A` and `B` that are subtypes of each other.

Comment: @pk1914, I've added a pattern that can be used to improve the usability of such hierarchy. However, it's hard to tell whether it's useful for you without knowing the actual use cases.